# How to retrieve json column with a native query with projection?

Tags: json, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-native-query

I have a database with a table that contains a column of type JSON. Retrieving all data from the table using the whole entity work without problems. But in a case when I use a native query with some joins and want to retrieve only specific columns Hibernate can't map properly the JSON column.
In other cases when are no JSON columns I use interface projections and everything works fine.
How can I retrieve the JSON column with projection?

My entity class is like this:

```
@Entity
public class EntityWithJsonColumn
...
@Type(type = "jsonb")
@Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
private Map<String,Object> additionalInfo;
...
```

and projection:

```
public interface DataProjection {
...
@Value("#{target.id}")
Long getID();

@Value("#{target.additionalInfo}")
Map<String,Object> getAdditionalInfo();
...
}
```

The error is `No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111;`

Comment: [@vlad-mihalcea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1025118/vlad-mihalcea) help with this pls, I have the same question, help me how to do this...